# Is there a way to make a google apps script always available? (google form/response sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that I use on the response sheet that results from a google form. I would like this script to always be available on any response sheet that gets created from a google form. I think I need to turn my script into an add-on, but I haven't found a simple explanation on how to do that.

Comment: I've voted to close your question as being "to broad."  For general usage questions, it's better to use a forum like [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).  Apps Script is a Web App.  It's not software that you install on your computer.  It runs in a browser.  If you are asking about how to set up an Add-on, that's not a programming question, although, it's done through the code editor, and questions about the code editor are also okay I guess.  But I still think it's better if you ask the question in Web Applications.

Comment: There is a Google community just for Add-ons:  [Developing Add-ons for Google](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: OK, thanks for the guidance.

Comment: you can ask here, but first show us your attempts at making the addon and specific problems you encountered.